# jquery script to generate form elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

i have a simple jquery script which allow me to create text boxes beside the uploaded files

```
$(function(){

    //------------- Plupload php upload  -------------//
    // Setup html4 version
    $("#html4_uploader").pluploadQueue({
        // General settings
        runtimes : 'html4', 
        url : '../../assets/dashboard/php/upload.php',
        max_file_size : '10mb',
        max_file_count: 15, // user can add no more then 15 files at a time
        chunk_size : '5mb',
        multiple_queues : true,

        // Rename files by clicking on their titles
        rename: true,

        // Sort files
        sortable: true,
    });

    var uploader = $('#html4_uploader').pluploadQueue();
    uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, info) {
            if (uploader.files.length == (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                $('.gradient').hide();

                form    = '<form class="form-horizontal" id="form-validate" novalidate="novalidate" method="post">';
                length  = uploader.files.length;
                files   = uploader.files;

                for (var i = 0; i <= length-1; i++) {
                    form+= '<div class="alert alert-success" id="message" style="display:none;"></div>';
                    form+= '<div class="form-row row-fluid">';
                    form+= '<div class="span12">';
                    form+= '<div class="row-fluid">';
                    form+= '<label class="form-label span3" for="medianame">File Title</label>';
                    form+= '<input class="span3 text" id="medianame'+i+'" name="mediatitle[]" type="text">';
                    form+= '<input type="hidden" name="mediapath[]" value="'+files[i].name+'" >';
                    form+= '<strong style="margin-right:20px;" >'+files[i].name+'</strong>';
                    form+= '</div>';
                    form+= '</div>';
                 };

                 form+= '<div class="form-row row-fluid">';
                 form+= '<div class="span12">';
                 form+= '<div class="row-fluid">';
                 form+= '<div class="form-actions">';
                 form+= '<div class="span3"></div>';
                 form+= '<div class="span9 controls">';
                 form+= '<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn marginR10" style="margin:10px;" >Save</button>';
                 form+= '<button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>';
                 form+= '</div>';                  
                 form+= '</div>';
                 form+= '</div>';
                 form+= '</div>';
                 form+= '</div>';
                 form+= '</form>';
                 $('#multiform').html(form);

                 $('#submit').click(function()
                 {
                        $.ajax
                        ({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: $('form').serialize(),
                            cache: false,
                            beforeSend: function()
                            {
                                $('#message').hide();
                            },
                            success: function(data)
                            {
                                if(data.response)
                                {
                                    $('#message').show().html(data.message);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                 });
            }
        });

});
```

the script just working fine but have a single issue
when it create the text boxes the first text box work fine but all other boxes are disable i can't click on them to write text 
i tried to modify it a lot of time but i can't figure out why this problem happened

Comment: Can you post a fiddle showing this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are generating duplicate `id`s.

You are creating a `div` with the `id` of "message" with each iteration of your for loop.  Having multiple elements with the same `id` is invalid HTML, as `id`s *must* be unique within a document.

When you select that `id` with a jQuery selector or `.getElementById()` it only selects the *first* one, because there aren't supposed to be any other elements with the same `id`.

Now there's also a problem with your `label` and its `for` attribute.  All of your labels are pointing to an element with the `id` of "medianame".  That should be changed to

```
<label class="form-label span3" for="medianame'+i+'">FileTitle</label>
```

to match the input generated on the next line.